# Can I recover an entire deleted Directory?

Tags: directory

In my haste to close the Magento tab on my computer, I accidentally deleted an entire Directory with 30+ galleries. The respective links are still in exsistence, but not the directory itself. Is there any way to recover the entire group of galleries and their overarching directory?